# Material io components and Hybrid apps

Tags: material-design, material-ui, materialize

I am planning on building a hybrid app and planning on using Material.io because of cognitive science behind the components.But I am struggling to understand if I can get the same component can behave differently in Mobile and Desktop ? Do I need to have multiple codebases for website and Mobile which seems overkill from maintenance and releasing new features.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is definitely opinion based.

It depends on what you are actually trying to build really.  Some components are mobile responsive and and material.io has somethings like the [Responsive Layout Grid.](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#)

From my work with material.io, I found that creating multiple layouts for mobile/desktop to be actually quite quick, although the project gets a bit bloated with code, I find the speed a good trade off.

> Do I need to have multiple codebases for website and Mobile

I would stick with material designs built in [media breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/) and keep all code with in the same codebase.  Less of a maintenance issue that way.  Once again though, my opinion